# Problem when trying to get a DC motor to run using the L298N H-Bridge?

Tags: gpio, power, rpi.gpio, battery

My setup is as follows:

- Using this [motor controller board](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-l298n-dual-h-bridge-stepper-motor-driver-controller-board-module-for-arduino-robot.html), I have one DC motor (I'm new to electronics, so I'm not sure when I say it's rated at 1.5V, because one 1.5V AA battery on its own makes it run perfectly). This motor is connected to the OUT1 and OUT2 terminals on the H-bridge.
- I have one 1.5V AA battery, with its positive end connected to the VCC terminal, and it's negative end connected to the GND terminal. The RPi's +5V GPIO is connected to the +5V terminal, and the RPi's ground is connected to the GND terminal as well.
- GPIO pins 15 and 13 are connected to IN1 and IN2, respectively. I am using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbCdNh0TiUo) setup (with the code at 14:30, in case it didn't skip there. I do not have pins 7 and 11 in use, because I'm only controlling one motor).

After all of this, the motor does not run. I don't even know how to test where the problem lies. I have tried it with 2 and 3 batteries, still to no avail. I have also tried switching to IN3 and IN4, and even switching around the (True and False) parameters in the GPIO.output() function. Am I doing something wrong at all? I have nearly the exact same setup as the tutorial, with a few differences. Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motor driver board says VCC (motor supply voltage) should be between  5 and 35 volts.

From what you say you are only supplying about 1.5 volts.

Try 3 to 5 cells in series to get (say) between 4.5 to 7.5 volts.

If you can, use a multimeter to measure the voltages you are supplying.

It is probably best to remove the Pi 5V connection.  Leave the Pi ground connection in place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I removed the Pi's 5V connection and I'm using 5 batteries, still nothing :( The LED on the motor driver board doesn't turn on unless the Pi's 5V connection is in, not sure if that matters either

Comment: Are the batteries in series?  You really need a multimeter.  If the LED doesn't light that suggests the batteries are not supplying  enough power.

Comment: Yep they are! I feel like a fool for asking, but should the negative/positive end of the series be connected to GND and VCC, respectively, or the 5V terminal and VCC respectively?

Comment: The battery -ve to GND, battery +ve to VCC.  Pi GND to GND.

Comment: Yep that's how I have it, it's solved now! I am ashamed to say I didn't see that the battery pack had a broken metal contact and it wasn't in contact with one of the batteries in the series, I've been at this for two days and this was the reason aha, thanks a lot for your patience appreciate it :) it needed 4 batteries minimum!

Comment: If the motor is rated at 1.5V you can use PWM to effectively cut the supply voltage.  E.g. 50% dutycycle PWM will give a voltage of say 2.5 volts (This assumes the batteries supply 6V and the motor driver circuitry loses 1 to leave 5V for the motor).